# Regular Expressions in DB2 SQL

Tags: sql, regex, db2

(Other than using a UDF) Any REGEXP-In-SQL support for DB2 9.7 ?

Comment: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/0301stolze/0301stolze.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no built-in support for regular expressions in DB2 9.7.

The only way is using UDFs or table functions as described in the article 'OMG Ponies' added in the comment.

@dan1111: I do not appreciate my post being edited, especially if people can't read the question correctly. The OP asked *Any REGEXP-In-**SQL** support for DB2 9.7*

SQL is not XQuery !!!

Sorry, don't delete the text of my 100% correct answer. You can add a comment or write your own answer.

Comment: This is not true. Regular expression were supported in DB2 9.7 via xQuery with the matches function: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.xml.doc/doc/xqrfnmat.html

Comment: @TannerFaulkner it's about time. ;-) IBM is always late with adding the obvious.

Answer (score 9):

Starting with DB2 11.1 there is built-in regex support. One of the new function is [`REGEXP_SUBSTR`](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0061497.html) and there are some more.

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('hello to you', '.o',1,1) 
   FROM sysibm.sysdummy1
```

Answer (score 7):

I'm komikoni(Keisuke Konishi).

I created the regular expression function (UDF) which does not exist in db2.
The UDF using the SQL/XML(Xquery).
You can easily install.

List of regular expressions provide UDF

1. **REG_MATCHES**
   provides Coincidence existence ( Scalar )
2. **REG_REPLACE**
   string substitution ( Scalar )
3. **REG_COUNT**
   number of matches retrieved ( Scalar )
4. **REG_POSITION**
   match position acquisition ( Scalar )
5. **REG_SUBSTR**
   gets a string matching ( Scalar )
6. **REG_SUBSTR_TABLE**
   list of matching string information ( Table )
7. **REG_TOKENIZE_TABLE**
   list of mismatched string information (divided by a separator string) ( Table )
8. **REG_ALLTOKEN_TABLE**
   list of mismatch string and matching string information ( Table )

Scripts can be downloaded from here.
(Sorry in Japanese)

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/jp/data/library/db2/j_d-regularexpression/

(English : [Machine translation](http://translate.googleusercontent.com/translate_c?hl=en&rurl=translate.google.com&tl=en&twu=1&u=http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/jp/data/library/db2/j_d-regularexpression/&usg=ALkJrhh5RyBAq5yIEe8ujHL10EI1-dQ-CA) Script : The last of a Japanese page)

I look forward to your feedback and comments.

Answer (score 6):

The real answer is that DB2 *does* support regular expression since PureXML was added (v9.7 included) via xQuery with the matches function.

For example:

```
db2 "with val as (
 select t.text
 from texts t
 where xmlcast(xmlquery('fn:matches(\$TEXT,''^[A-Za-z 0-9]*$'')') as integer) = 0
)
select * from val"
```

For more information:

- http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.xml.doc/doc/xqrfnmat.html

Answer (score 5):

That works fine except for DB2 z/OS - in DB2 v10 z/OS you must use PASSING as follows

```
   with val as (
     select t.text
     from texts t
     where xmlcast(xmlquery('fn:matches($v,"^[A-Za-z 0-9]*$")'
                    PASSING t.text as "v" ) as integer) = 0
    )
    select * from val
```