# Can we use "NOT LIKE " in sql

Tags: sql, regex, db2, sql-like

Can we use `"NOT LIKE '%abc%'"`  just opposite of `LIKE '%abc%'` ?
i tried and got some result but dont look like correct!!

Is there anything similar to `regex in SQL`.

Eg:

i hae a table with 3 field.

```
id  name  address
1    xyz    1234 abcd 
2    abc    nomans land
3    omg    #123 new-york
3    nom    $123 &7up
```

can i fetch the address ****with special characters with out checking each special** character one by one . How

Comment: Does existence of Db2 tag mean **Is there regex in DB2**?

Comment: :-) am using db2 .. but question is about general sql !

Comment: By googling I discovered that even sql server does have some support of it. But it is not widely used. Regex row lookup is expensive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, look [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/0301stolze/0301stolze.html). Also NOT LIKE is supported.

Comment: Just to complete the answer, [Related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4763757/regular-expressions-in-db2-sql);

Comment: Shocking that a link at ibm.com has survived so long.  In case the link goes dead, here is some helpful text [preceded by the navigation] for locating it again:
developerWorks->Technical topics->Information Management->Technical library
**Bringing the Power of Regular Expression Matching to SQL**
The ability to find patterns in a string is a common scenario in many text-based applications. This article describes how to extend DB2 to integrate a library for regular expression matching into DB2, thereby making the task much easier and more efficient.
Knut StolzeIBM Germany
23 January 2003

Answer (score 6):

In SQL Server. if you wanted addresses that contained characters other than alphanumerics and spaces:

```
address LIKE '%[^0-9a-zA-Z ]%';
```

noting the `^` character means "any single character not within the specified range". Not sure if something very similar is possible in DB2.

Answer (score 4):

In db2 (version 9.7.900.250), I've successfully specified "not like" this way:

```
select * from orders
where not(orders.order_number like 'S%')
```

This shows all orders where the order# does NOT start with a capital "S".

Comment: Been looking this for a while, thanks mate.

Answer (score 2):

No description was given for what was "tried and got some result but don't look like correct!!" with regard to the Subject inquiry, but in review of the given data and the two predicates from the OP, consider the following; noting, the secondary *regex* inquiry is apparently already answered and accepted, so is ignored in this response:

```
with
  xmp (id, name, address) as
( values ( 1  ,  'xyz'  ,  '1234 abcd '    )
       , ( 2  ,  'abc'  ,  'nomans land'   )
       , ( 3  ,  'omg'  ,  '#123 new-york' )
       , ( 3  ,  'nom'  ,  '$123 &7up'     )
)
select id
from xmp
where address NOT LIKE '%abc%'
```

The above DB2 query should yield the set {(2), (3), (3)}; i.e. include all but the first row.  Changing the predicate from `address NOT LIKE '%abc%'` to `address LIKE '%abc%'` should yield the set {(1)}; i.e. include only the first row.  The specification of the predicate in either form `address NOT LIKE '%abc%'` or `NOT (address LIKE '%abc%')` should yield the same result; they are logically identical requests.