# Select query with Substring & Instr in DB2

Tags: java, sql, db2

[image: Please see the image]
I want to Select only those records of table **TEST**, having **TEMPPATH** value ends with IN ('XGENCISB.CPY', 'XCISTABT.CPY').

NOTE: These IN clause values will be set at run time

Please tell if this possible in a single query using sub-string??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this possible to look up the name of files after last "\" char in a single SELECT query e.g. First pick the all names from last "\" and then search the given names in a IN clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this too: With `Right` and [`upper`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2.doc.sqlref%2Ffupper.htm):

```
select * from TEST where upper(Right(TEMPPATH,4)) = '.CPY'
AND TEMPPATH IS NOT NULL;
```

- If you are interested in `regexp`, take a look at this as well: [Regular Expressions in DB2 SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4763757/regular-expressions-in-db2-sql)

---

### EDIT as per OP's udpates on the question

Given that theset two string will be in the same length(12 or adjust accordingly), you can try

```
select * from TEST where upper(Right(TEMPPATH,12)) 
IN ('XGENCISB.CPY', 'XCISTABT.CPY')
AND TEMPPATH IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: @Kishore this one will bring both into `upper case` :)

Comment: Happy to hear you got it worked :D a note on `index`, if you will be doing this search in large scale it's best that you [`reverse`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r5/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2.luw.xml.doc%2Fdoc%2Fxqrfnrvs.html) this string and store it in another column giving an index. Makes things perform better.

Comment: Actually my requirement was to select multiple records in 1 query, as I updated the question, plz tell if you know.

Comment: @Kishore I have updated accordingly, give it try and let us know :)

Comment: Is this possible to look up the name of files after last "\" char in a single SELECT query e.g. First pick the all names from last "\" and then search the given names in a IN clause.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from TEST where TEMPPATH LIKE '%.CPY' OR TEMPPATH LIKE '%.cpy'
```

Comment: Thx  @Neji, But what about if any record having lower case data e.g. ".cpy" or ".CpY" type data. USACE can be applied on where condition??

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution of the CASES you asked from @Neji:

```
    select * from TEST where lower(TEMPPATH) LIKE (lower('%.cpy'));
```