# In Crystal Report how to display XML data stored in database Table

Tags: xml, crystal-reports

I have XML data stored in the Employee table column; the datatype is XML in DB2.

A sample:

```
<employee id="901">
  <name>
    <first>Mubashar</first> 
    <last>Hussain</last>
  </name>
  <office>344</office>
  <salary currency="USD">55000</salary>
</employee>
```

Now I want to display XML stored data in crystal report and want to design a report to list all employees from this field.

I don't want to XML datasource approach because there are hundreds of employees registered.

Kindly help me how can I parse or display XML data stored in table column or suggest me 
best approach how can I proceed with XML data listing .

Looking forward your response, professionals.

Thanks & regards,

mHussain

Answer (score 0):

Your best option is perform a regular-expression search in a `sql-expression` field:

```
// {%EmployeeName}
(
    REG_SUBSTR(table.field, '<regular expression here>')
)
```

I don't have access to DB2, so I can't give you the exact syntax.

More information on DB2's regular-expression support: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4763757/regular-expressions-in-db2-sql)