# SQL function to filter out column values that start with 'ABC' or any three letters

Tags: sql, db2

I'm trying to adapt an SQL query to filter out any rows where the value in a specific column begins with three letters. For example, in the screenshot shown below, the only row I want the query to return is row 11: `(13, '0511:15', 'FT20')`.  Is there a function in DB2 that I can use to accomplish this?

My simple query is:

```
select pat.f1, hos.hpid, hos.hpcd
from patall3 pat
join hospidl1 hos on pat.f1=hos.hpacct
order by pat.f1;
```

I'm not familiar at all with DB2 but I hope there is a way to accomplish this. Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: You could use an XPath `matches` function, as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4763757/regular-expressions-in-db2-sql). The regular expression in your case might look like `^[a-zA-Z]{3}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `TRANSLATE` function to determine if `LEFT( LTRIM( hos.hpid ), 3 )` contains letters.

Calling the `TRANSLATE` function in the following manner replaces all uppercase capital letters from the input string with the letter A:

```
TRANSLATE( inputString, 
   'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA', 
   'BCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
)
```

Here's how to restrict the `TRANSLATE` function to evaluate just the first three characters of the column:

```
select pat.f1, hos.hpid, hos.hpcd
from patall3 pat
join hospidl1 hos on pat.f1=hos.hpacct
where TRANSLATE( 
    LEFT( LTRIM( hos.hpid ), 3 ),
    'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA', 
    'BCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
 ) <> 'AAA'
order by pat.f1;
;
```

That query will only block values that contain letters for *all* of the first three characters ('AAA', 'AAB', 'AAC', etc.). If you'd rather block rows that contain a letter in *any* of the first three characters, then use this query instead:

```
select pat.f1, hos.hpid, hos.hpcd
from patall3 pat
join hospidl1 hos on pat.f1=hos.hpacct
where TRANSLATE( 
    LEFT( LTRIM( hos.hpid ), 3 ),
    'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA', 
    'BCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
 ) NOT LIKE '%A%'
order by pat.f1;
;
```

Comment: Thanks Fred. Looks like that is almost there. If there are blank spaces before the record, for example '  TFC2186', this does not remove them.  Is there a way to strip off all blank spaces before this TRANSLATE is applied?

Comment: Yes. I've revised my answer to show how the `LTRIM` and `LEFT` functions can be combined.