# Use REGEXP_SUBSTR in DB2

Tags: db2, regexp-substr

I want to use something like REGEXP_SUBSTR in DB2 (version 10.5).

There is an example of what I tried:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('hello to you', '.o') 
FROM sysibm.sysdummy1
```

I got this error : [Error Code: -420, SQL State: 22018]

```
09:23:12  [SELECT - 0 row(s), 0.000 secs]  [Error Code: -420, SQL State: 22018]  DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-420, SQLSTATE=22018, SQLERRMC=INTEGER, DRIVER=3.57.82
... 1 statement(s) executed, 0 row(s) affected, exec/fetch time: 0.000/0.000 sec  [0 successful, 0 warnings, 1 errors]
```

Comment: Do you want to use any regular expression or just search for string snippets? DB2 does not have regex_substr. Your options depend on what you want to do.

Comment: 1- I want to test if a column contains the regular expression, than extract it to be used by another column. Example,      update table_name  set column_name = REGEXP_SUBSTR(column2_name,'^[A-Za-z0-9]*$') where condition;

Comment: Look at this Stackoverflow question on how to emulate it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4763757/regular-expressions-in-db2-sql

Comment: REGEXP_SUBSTR does not exist in DB2! The way to use regular expressions is with xquery (I already answered that question). What you can do is to wrap the xquery into a UDF in order to have the function you said. Also, you can install a set of stored procedure that provide regular expressions (look in DeveloperWorks)

Answer (score 0):

There is no equivalent function to `REGEXP_SUBSTR` in DB2.

However you can achieve similar results with the `XMLQUERY` function

```
SELECT 
  XMLCAST(
   XMLQUERY('fn:replace($src,"^hello | you$","")' 
   PASSING 'hello to you' AS "src")
  AS VARCHAR(255))
FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1;
```

**Difficulty** Here, fn:replace *removes* matched patterns because DB2's implementation doesn't support `()` and `$1` sub-grouping patterns

Answer (score 0):

With `DB2 V11.1` there is now `REGEXP_SUBSTR()`. It works simply as [this](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0061497.html):

## Example 1

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('hello to you', '.o',1,1) 
   FROM sysibm.sysdummy1Copy
```

> Return the string which matches any character preceding a 'o'.
>
> The result is 'lo'.

## Example 2

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('hello to you', '.o',1,2) 
   FROM sysibm.sysdummy1Copy
```

> Return the second string occurrence which matches any character preceding a 'o'.
>
> The result is 'to'.

## Example 3

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('hello to you', '.o',1,3) 
   FROM sysibm.sysdummy1
```

> Return the third string occurrence which matches any character preceding a 'o'.
>
> The result is 'yo'.