# How to find ASCII of every character in string using DB2 Function?

Tags: sql, loops, db2, ascii, user-defined-functions

I have written a function in DB2 - that is calculating ASCII of records in a particular column. I want to some help as I want to check the ASCII of every single character in string return yes if the ASCII of that record is greater than 127.

```sql
BEGIN
ATOMIC DECLARE POS,
INT;

IF INSTR IS NULL THEN RETURN NULL;

END IF;

SET
(
    POS,
    LEN
)=(
    1,
    LENGTH(INSTR)
);


WHILE POS <= LEN DO IF ASCII( SUBSTR( INSTR, POS, 1 ))> 128 THEN RETURN 'Y';

END IF;

SET
POS = POS + 1;

END WHILE;


RETURN 'N';
```

Comment: I think using regular expressions is a lot easier. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4763757/regular-expressions-in-db2-sql.

Comment: Yes , I have written regular expression also. But first i want to take out all the special characters from a particular table in database. That table has million of records. For that i am thinking to write a function that will give me records having special characters that have ascii greater than 127. I want to calculate ascii of every character in that column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why to calculate ascii of every character in that column, if the goal is just to get such rows?

```
SELECT STR
FROM 
(
VALUES 
  'Hello, world'
, 'Привет, мир'
) T (STR)
WHERE xmlcast(xmlquery('fn:matches($s, "[^\x00-\x7F]")' passing t.str as "s") as int) = 1;
```

The [fn:matches](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.xml.doc/doc/xqrfnmat.html) function uses regular expressions.
The `[^\x00-\x7F]` regular expression means "a character with hex value not in the `0x00 - 0x7F` interval". If a value of passed `t.str` contains such a character, the function returns 1 and 0 otherwise.

Comment: Can you please explain this query ?

Comment: What does this mean a character with hex value not in the 0x00 - 0x7F interval ? Other than these means extra character ?

Comment: S-ASCII is a character set (and an encoding) with some notable features:

Values are between 0–127 (x00–x7F)

ASCII code-point 32 (decimal) represents a SPACE

ASCII code-point 65 represents the uppercase letter A

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to check if a UTF-8 value in DB2 only contains "plain ASCII" is to compare it's BYTE length with it's STRINGUNITS32 length. E.g.

```
SELECT
    S
,   LENGTHB(S) AS BYTES
,   LENGTH4(S) AS CHARACTERS 
,   LENGTHB(S) = LENGTH4(S) PLAIN_ASCII
FROM 
    TABLE(VALUES ('123!"$'),('¹²³€½¾')) T(S)
```

returns

```
S     |BYTES|CHARACTERS|PLAIN_ASCII
------|-----|----------|-----------
123!"$|    6|         6|true       
¹²³€½¾|   13|         6|false
```

The above assumes your database is Unicode, and the columns are VARCHAR. If they are VARGRAPHIC (i.e. UTF-16), then you would need to cast them to VARCHAR in your comparision